# What does HTTP code 172 mean?

Tags: apache-2.2, http

browsing access logs, sometimes I see

`"POST / HTTP/1.0" 200`

which should be OK

but other times I see

`"POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 172`

What does the 172 next to 200 mean?

Also, I see a few with 7250, or 44

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a post to the access log, which by default is formatted like this:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
```

Where %b is your elusive '172', the size of the response in bytes. see [this site.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)

Answer (score 9):

> The last entry indicates the size of the object returned to the client, not including the response headers. If no content was returned to the client, this value will be "-".

From: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog, Section *Common Log Format*

Answer (score 3):

According to Ken Quon at [this link](http://www.quora.com/In-an-HTTP-log-file-HTTP-1-1-200-3880-the-200-is-a-response-code-but-what-is-the-number-after-the-200):

> For default Apache log files, that would be the size of the object
>   (number of bytes) returned to the client, not including the response
>   headers. If no content was returned to the client, this value will be
>   "-".